# How to retrieve both "associated" records and "associated through" records in a performant way?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I am trying to improve an SQL query in order to retrieve both "associated" records and "associated through" records (`ActiveRecord::Associations`) in a performant way so to avoid the "*N + 1 query problem*". That is, I have:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_relationships

  has_many :categories,
    :through => :category_relationships
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_relationships

  has_many :articles,
    :through => :article_relationships
end
```

In a couple of SQL queries (that is, in a "performant way", maybe by using the Ruby on Rails  `includes()` method) *I would like to retrieve both `categories` and `category_relationships`*, *or both `articles` and `article_relationships`*.

**How can I make that?**

---

P.S.: I am improve queries like the followings:

```
@category = Category.first

articles = @category.articles.where(:user_id => @current_user.id)
articles.each do |article|
  # Note: In this example the 'inspect' method is just a method to "trigger" the
  # "eager loading" functionalities
  article.category_relationships.inspect
end
```

Comment: What query exactly are you going to optimize?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Article.includes(:category_relationships => :categories).find(1)
```

Which will reduce this to 3 queries (1 for each table). For performance, also make sure your foreign keys have an index.

But in general, I'm curious why the "category_relationships" entity exists at all, and why this isn't a has_and_belongs_to sort of situation?

**Updated**

As per your changed question, you can still do

```
Category.includes(:article_relationships => :articles).first
```

If you watch the console (or tail log/development) you'll see that when you call the associations, it'll hit the cached values and you're golden.

But I am still curious why you're not using a Has and Belongs To Many association.

Comment: And if I use some statement including a `where` method like: `Article.includes(:category_relationships => :categories).where(:user_id => 1)`? I get same results (regarding the performance)? *BTW*: How the `includes()` really works?